# BCM4311 Wireless driver will not work on any Ubuntu distro's past 10.10, and I cannot figure out why

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 onto an older Dell Latitude D520 (it's the only disc I had till I connected to the net, and grabbed the newest distro) and the wireless drivers installed and connected just fine.

I first tried the easy route (upgrading to 12.10 through Update Manager) but it errored  out and would not let me update/upgrade.
so I just downloaded the ISO and tried to install it via disc. but this time, the wireless will just not work for me. (after much diligence) I finally found the new Software Center that contains the Additional Drivers program. it says that I am using the Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernal-source (proprietary). but my wireless light will not turn on after hitting the "fn+wireless button" and in my network finder it only says "Wired Network - Disconnected" it doesn't list anything about Wireless.
it doesn't say "wireless disabled" or "wireless disconnected". it just shows status for wired connections.

I've tried this with 12.10, 12.04, 11.10, 11.04, and 10.10 is the latest distro that allows me to use wireless. and because it's so out of date, it will not update/upgrade at all.
my other major setback, is I do not have any ethernet at my disposal at the moment. I cannot connect to my router aside from my wireless signal. so updating my repositories doesn't work either.

if there is anything I can do, I would love to know. I am fairly computer savvy, but most of my skill is in windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It possibly is a duplicate indeed. In addition to installing firmware referenced in Luis' link, you will also need to remove the STA driver: sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source.

Answer (score 0):

open the ‘Synaptic Package Manager‘ (if you are using Ubuntu 11.10 then install it first from the software cemter) and search for ‘bcm’
uninstall the ‘bcm-kernel-source‘ package
make sure that the ‘firmware-b43-installer‘ and the ‘b43-fwcutter‘ packages are installed
type into terminal:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | egrep '8180|acx|at76|ath|b43|bcm|CX|eth|ipw|irmware|isl|lbtf|orinoco|ndiswrapper|NPE|p54|prism|rtl|rt2|rt3|rt6|rt7|witch|wl'
```

see if the term ‘blacklist bcm43xx‘ is there

if it is, then type cd /etc/modprobe.d/ and then sudo gedit blacklist.conf put a # in front of the line: blacklist bcm43xx then save the file (I was getting error messages in the terminal about not being able to save, but it actually did save properly).
reboot

Source: http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/05/how-to-solve-no-wireless-networks-in-ubuntu-11-04/